# groovy list to map

Tags: groovy

How can I transform this list to a map?

```
def list = [[10, STOREA, NORTH], [9, STOREB, CENTER], [11, STOREC, CENTER]]
```

Like to:

```
def map = [['NORTH': ['STORE': 'STOREA', 'QTY': 10]],['CENTER': ['STORE': 'STOREB', 'QTY': 9],['STORE': 'STOREC', 'QTY': 11]]
```

I started to doing each on `list.each` and add an new parameter but I had no success

Comment: This is not about `grails`, is `groovy` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `groupBy` and `collectEntries`.  `groupBy` creates a map by a closure, that returns the key to collect all items with the same key in.  Then `collectEntries` builds you a map by returning key and value (as a list) from that closure.  And as the groupby-map holds all the original list items, we `collect` them into a new map with the STORE/QTY keys.

```
def list = [[10, 'STOREA', 'NORTH'], [9, 'STOREB', 'CENTER'], [11, 'STOREC', 'CENTER']]

def map = list.groupBy{ it[2] }.collectEntries{
    [it.key, it.value.collect{ [STORE: it[1], QTY: it[0]] }]
}

println map.inspect()
//=> ['NORTH':[['STORE':'STOREA', 'QTY':10]], 'CENTER':[['STORE':'STOREB', 'QTY':9], ['STORE':'STOREC', 'QTY':11]]]
```

Comment: Only gives me one center, theres two